# How to convert image from file input to base64 url in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, base64

I have tried to convert an image from file input in vue, I'm not so sure I did it in the proper way.
What I want to achieve is to get the Image url, assign it to a data variable and push it into my mongoose DB

That's what I tried based on a guide I read:

**Input:**

```
    <div class="singleInput50">
      <span>Personal Image:</span>
      <input type="file" @change="handleImage" accept="image/*">
    </div>
```

**HandleImage:**

```
handleImage(e) {
      const selectedImage = e.target.files[0];
      this.createBase64Image(selectedImage);
    },
```

**createBase64Image:**

```
createBase64Image(fileObject) {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.userObject.imgPersonal = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileObject)
  console.log("file object", fileObject);
}
```

**ImgPersonal value after the functions has been executed:**

```
imgPersonal:"ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC\n \n  \n$ &%# #"(-90(*6+"#2D26;=@@@&0FKE>J9?@=ÿÛC =)#)==================================================ÿÀ"ÿÄ \nÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br \n%&'()*456789:CDEFGH
```

**I have tried also with readAsDataURL(), seems like the same outcome**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this function to convert files to base64. Works fine for me:

```js
export default function (blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onerror = reject
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  })
}
```

Comment: Actually That was my mistake and it's seems to work just fine. Thanks for the answer I'll approve it :)